# .aspx character coding

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding, special-characters, character

I am having an problem. First time working with a windows server, do you know if there is any problem in character coding? My document is set to **content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"** but it's giving me funny words... you can check it [here](http://www2.csdm.qc.ca/MarcFavreau/2010/projet-educatif.aspx). This site is a pure HTML with few includes but anything else is just HTML.

I can convert them to HTML entities but that is basically wasting my time. I never had this problem with any website I did except for this.

Some others said "The problems seems to be that you have converted the text into utf-8 twice.". But how would Coverted it twice since dreamweaver should convert it for me but in this case it doesn't.

Comment: It's in French - I don't know French. Can you give some examples of funny words?

Comment: I have fixed it my just changing the encoding from UTF-8 to ISO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution I don't know why but .... here is my solution...

**before**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 " />
```

**after**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 " />
```

Just by changing the character set has fixed my problem.....

Comment: So the source is really in latin1? Then you, indeed, need to specify *proper* encoding, as you have done, or (preferably in XXI century) stick to UTF-8 and recode the source to it.